# AWS Aurora - How to enable serverless mode via CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, serverless, amazon-aurora, aws-serverless

I am using the following command to create AWS Aurora Serverless instance

```
aws rds create-db-cluster --db-cluster-identifier test-cluster --database-name testdb --master-username test --master-user-password testtest --engine aurora --engine-mode serverless --region us-east-1
```

but I am getting the following error.

> Unknown options: --engine-mode, serverless

Above command works great on my AWS account but its not working on my clients account. (I just have programmatic access to that account). I have double check the permissions and I have the similar permissions as of my own account.

Summary: AWS command to create serverless aurora cluster is working on one account but not on another account with similar permissions.

Account 1: 
[image: account1]

Account2: 
[image: acc2]

Comment: Hi John, do you mind accepting one of the answers if you think it helped. Do let us know if you need any more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I was using awscli version 1.14 on my server and 1.16 on my laptop. I updated the awscli and now its working fine.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade awscli
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message states that it does not know about the `engine-mode` argument. This is a clear indication that your AWS CLI version is out dated. Serverless was added as part of a recent (late 2018) release, so you need to update your client's AWS CLI to recognize these inputs.